# XPath command to give conditions for child and grandchild elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0, domxpath

I want to get specific nodes values from XML File using XPath in Java

```
<country>
    <countryName>India</countryName>
    <city>
        <name>Mumbai</name>
        <hotel>
            <hotelName>Marriott</hotelName>
            <capacity>500</capacity>
        </hotel>
        <hotel>
            <hotelName>ITC</hotelName>
            <capacity>400</capacity>
        </hotel>
    </city>
    <city>
        <name>Bangalore</name>
        <hotel>
            <hotelName> ITC</hotelName>
            <capacity>250</capacity>
        </hotel>
    </city>
</country>
<country>
    <countryName>Australia</countryName>
    <city>
        <name>Sydney</name>
        <hotel>
            <hotelName>Marriott</hotelName>
            <capacity>200</capacity>
        </hotel>
    </city>
</country>
```

Now I want the **Capacity** of **hotels** from a specific country using xpath commands.
The conditions go like this -
In ** Country = India, City = Mumbai, Hotel = Marriott**

There could be more countries and cities with same hotel names in them.

What I did was

`//country[normalize-space(name)="India" and normalize-space(city/name)="Mumbai" and normalize-space(city/hotel)="Marriott"]/city/capacity/text()`

But this gives me an output for all the Hotel capacities inside country India!

Please help with the command, I don't know where I am going wrong or what I should change

Comment: Please note there are two typos in your sample input/xpath.  There is an improperly closed hotel node and the sample xpath refers to a country "name" node instead of "countryName".

Comment: Thanks, I've rectified it now

Answer (score 1):

The predicate (the conditions in the square brackets) in your approach are selecting a country based on the existence of children/grandchildren nodes, and then selecting all city/capacity within that country.  If you are always intending to target a single specific hotel then associate the predicates to each level of the hierarchy, for example:

```
//country[normalize-space(countryName)="India"]/city[normalize-space(name)="Mumbai"]/hotel[normalize-space(hotelName)="Marriott"]/capacity/text()
```

Which returns 500.  This selects the capacity text for hotels named "Marriott" within cities named "Mumbai" within countries named "India".

Comment: For the xml that I'm using it for, I can't really hardcode it like that because the xml isn't going to be the same, but the structure would be similar!
How can I write the command with the same conditions but not being so specific about the conditions (not hardcoding) ??

Comment: That is quite a different question than the one you asked.  You haven't shared any information about how you are constructing the XPath.  XPath itself doesn't have variables so you would need to use XQuery or any scripting/programming language where you can dynamically construct the XPath.  I answered the question you directly asked (why is your explicit XPath not returning your expected results).

Comment: Yes yes you answered my question to the point! I was asking you this in the comment in addition to that question as I saw that you have a lot knowledge in this than me. I shall check XQuery or other ways to dynamically construct the xpath.

I can't hardcode because I receive the xml file from a live server and not all element changes may be reflected at every time. This xml was an example and not the real one.

Comment: Actually, there are about 100s of such elements with completely different names but the structure is the same, so I was looking for a way to write a generic line of code which takes element names from a file and autoconstructs such a command. But the number of child and grandchild nodes is variable